# How to retrieve wide partition from cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

We have some large partition in cassandra and I would like to see what caused the large partition. Is there a tool to get the partition data out of cassandra and analyze it ? Right now cqlsh query is timing out even if select single row from the partition.

Comment: how wide of a partition you talking about?

Comment: It is around 3Gb. I have another set up where it is only 299 MB. Here the reason seems to be with coordinator node being timeout.

Comment: whats current heap settings?

Comment: 3gb isn't that bad, id start with just increasing key_cache_size_in_mb and column_index_size_in_kb in yaml and make sure heap is large enough.

Answer (score 1):

It can depend on why you get the timeout but theres a some of options.

- increase `column_index_size_in_kb` in your `cassandra.yaml` to something like 1024 and rebuild the sstables. This works around the object allocation issues a wide partition index introduces.
- increasing heap size.
- increase `read_request_timeout_in_ms`
- increase key cache size (`nodetool setcachecapacity 1000 0 0`) then make the read. Watch the read stage until down to zero then try request again. This is hard unless cluster is essentially unused. The read continues even after the timeout, once it finishes reading the index it will cache it so the following read will skip that part (generally the worst) which will speed up significantly
- pull raw data from sstable with sstabledump or [sstabletools](https://github.com/tolbertam/sstable-tools)